# Error in producing venn diagrams using nVennR

Tags: r, algorithm, venn-diagram

I am hoping to create a complex Venn Diagram with my own data in R using the [nVennR package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nVennR/index.html) created by [Pérez-Silva et al. 2018](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/34/13/2322/4904268). I am running the sample code in [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nVennR/vignettes/nVennR.html).

When I run the sample code, R shows a warning message:

```
The figure cannot be rendered in the plot window. Please, use the arguments outFile and/or systemShow.
```

After setting the systemShow argument to TRUE, Chrome attempts to open the SVG file and displays the following error:

```
error on line 74 at column 45: Namespace prefix xlink for href on use is not defined.
```

Not sure why I'm unable to generate an image using the code provided!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After installing the `rsvg` and `grImport2` packages, the plot should be displayed as in the vignette:

```
plotVenn(list(SAS=sas, PYTHON=python, R=rr), nCycles = 2000)
```

If you want to view the plot in a web browser, save it to a file

```
plotVenn(list(SAS=sas, PYTHON=python, R=rr), nCycles = 2000, outFile="a.svg")
```

and change the first line

```
<svg width="700" height="500">
```

to

```
<svg width="700" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

The file can be viewed in SVG editors such as Inkscape without modification.

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked like a charm! Hope this helps others that ran into this same issue.